# How to differentiate an integral where the independent variable doesn't appear as a limit of integration

Tags: integration

I woke up this morning in sweat when I realized that I had never considered how to differentiate:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int\limits_a^b f(z,x)\ dz$$

I can't use the fundamental theorem here because $x$ isn't a limit of integration, so what can I do?

- Can I break up the integral into two parts $[a, x]$ and $[x, b]$?
- Because the integral is really a linear operator and the derivative is a linear operator, can I rewrite my expression as

$$ \int\limits_a^b \frac{d}{dx} f(z,x)\ dz =\int\limits_a^b f_x(z,x)\ dz$$

Is this a multivariable calculus integral in which case I'd need more machinery than I currently am familiar with?

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: So I happen to be correct with this one.

Comment: assuming $f$ nice enough, your expression is correct (but the argument is more involved than what you wrote; in general, you can't freely change the order of limits, infinite sums, etc)

Comment: Ok thanks. Is this related to the notion of uniform convergence? If so it came up in a discussion this morning about differentiating a fourier series.

Comment: In a way, yes. The key idea is that you want to interchange a limit (the derivative) and an integral. So you want to use [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) and in this case you might also want to use uniform boundedness.

Comment: Essentially the minimum you need for the Riemann integral is $ \left\lvert \frac{f(z,x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f_x(z,x) \right\rvert \to 0 $ uniformly in $z$. For the Lebesgue integral, some use of Dominated Convergence is normally easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do from the definition of the derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int\limits_a^b f(z,x)\ dz
=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\int_a^b f(z,x+h)dz-\int_a^b f(z,x)dz}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0}\int_a^b\frac{f(z,x+h)-f(z,x)}{h} dz.$$

You can find a theorem (such as dominated convergence theorem) to ensure the exchange of the limit and the integral to obtain the desired equality.

However, if the function is good enough, your guess is right, you can check it by yourself.